# Create dynamic social network share Button

Tags: php, href, social-networking, share-button

My goal is to create a social network share button on job seeker website.

The idea is that jobs are published according to agent and the job ids, so i will like to share this job on social network.

**Example**

Share button

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=<?php echo "You may have experience of the following: Junior Web Developer, Technical Support, .Net, PHP, C#, Trainee Developer, IT Support, Helpdesk, Web Designer, Content Manager, CMS, Wed Editor, ASP.Net, VB.Net, Online Content Editor etc."."     ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">SHARE</a>
```

**Expected Result Sample**

You may have experience in this following: Junior Web Developer, Technical Support, .Net, PHP, C#, Trainee Developer, IT Support, Helpdesk, Web Designer, Content Manager, CMS, Wed Editor, ASP.Net, VB.Net, Online Content Editor etc.    dayjob.com/?j=4&Agent=rayJ345

**==**

The trouble is, when this button is click it produce some like this in which anything after **dayjob.com/?j=4** is eliminated or not included.

In nutshell i am getting **dayjob.com/?j=4** instead of  **dayjob.com/?j=4&Agent=rayJ345**

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to urlencode the string you're passing. Try this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=<?php echo rawurlencode("You may have experience of the following: Junior Web Developer, Technical Support, .Net, PHP, C#, Trainee Developer, IT Support, Helpdesk, Web Designer, Content Manager, CMS, Wed Editor, ASP.Net, VB.Net, Online Content Editor etc."."     ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">SHARE</a>
```

But also keep in mind that tweets shouldn't be longer than 140 characters.